# Headers not finding files inside folders

Tags: ios, objective-c, build, import, header

I'm working with a nested project where I have a bunch of files inside folders; the problem comes when I import them. I get an error saying `File not found`. But if I type the name of the parent folder, slash and the file name everything seems to work OK. So, I have to type `#import "Folder/File.h"` instead of `#import "File.h"`. I'm aware that there's an automatic way to do this.

I assume that this issue can be solved by modifying some of the parameters on build phases. But I'm not sure exactly what to do. Could you give me any advice? Thanks

**Edit**: This error only occurs when I do *Archive*. When I do *Build & Run* I don't get any error.

Comment: You should add the folder to header search path in build settings.

Comment: Do you mean by adding that: `$(TARGET_BUILD_DIR)/include/ParentFolder`? Where `ParentFolder` stands for the folder containing not only the files from where I'm trying to import the other files but also the folders where this files are inside.

Comment: If you want to type just the filename after #import, then you should add the path of the folder containing the file to header search paths.  If the error only occurs when you do archive, it seems your settings for release build is missing something.

Comment: Would you mind taking a look at this question of a friend of mine who is having the same issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17657878/header-search-paths-trouble-grabkit

Comment: I added a comment to your friend's question.

Comment: Thanks @cahn for your implication!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is probably a more elegant way of doing that. However, I typically solve that by adding the files to the xcode project.

Comment: You are relying on Xcode's obscure "header map". Not also setting header search paths is calling for trouble. ;)

Comment: I've just seen the answer and that's what we actually did and it worked properly. So, thanks! ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you have to add that folder to

```
USER_HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS
```

under the Build Settings Tab