# Header search paths trouble Grabkit

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, header-files, file-not-found

I'm developing a iOS 6 app for iPad and I use a Repository called Grabkit, which I have to add inside my project as a nested/sub project. In order to make it work I must add in Header Search Paths the following code:

> $(TARGET_BUILD_DIR)/include/GrabKitLib

So then it looks like that: [image]

It works pretty well in the simulator and even when I test it on my iPad, but the problem is that when I want to archive to send it to the App Store I get an error saying: "Grabkit.h file not found" I don't get this error when I'm testing the app so it's weird. What could be the problem? What can I do? Thanks

Comment: Does the file really exist in build/Release-iphoneos/include/GrabKitLib?  When you run your app, Xcode builds your app in debug mode (simulator or not).  To archive, Xcode tries to build in release mode.  Looks like you didn't build grabkit in release mode.

Comment: Did you end up fixing this?

Answer (score 0):

I fixd it by adding
`$(BUILD_ROOT)/../IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/include/GrabKitLib` in user header search path

```
skip install = NO
```

Comment: but i fixed it by keeping user header search path within ""

Comment: Huh?  Was your comment meant as an edit… or are you talking to yourself?